# Apple Watch 3 - How to track movement in tennis?

Tags: iphone, apple-watch

I have both an Apple Watch and iPhone. When I play tennis, my iPhone lays on the table. What setting do I need to set, in order for the watch to track my movement?

Currently it tracks the movement of the iPhone, so during my training, it stays at 0KM for the whole time. It works like this regardless if I use Endomondo or the Workout app.

Answer (score 1):

we have also developed a smartwatch app for the tennis players - [BestShot](http://bestshot.co)

It tracks both the tennis swings and the health data, combining it in a game performance scorecard, which can be accessed on a phone companion app. We have been working on it for a year and we are now testing it with a few tennis players and coaches. Hopefully you will find it useful too.

Comment: Does it allow exporting to Endomondo?

Comment: Does it automatically exports data into Health on iOS?

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to use the Other workout in the Workout app on Apple Watch. This is generally acceptable for workouts that are not already available in the Workout app, but you can also label the workout as tennis. This excerpt from the [Apple Watch User Guide](https://help.apple.com/watch/#/apd91635a9e6) explains how to label a workout —

> Start a workout with the type Other. When you’re done, swipe right, then tap End. Tap Name Workout, tap the type of workout you’ve finished—tennis or Tai Chi, for example—scroll to the bottom of the workout summary, then tap Done.

You can also use an app called [TennisKeeper](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tenniskeeper-tennis-tracker/id1097388824?mt=8), which offers an Apple Watch app as well. Though I have never used this app, its page on the App Store advertises Apple Watch integration —

> This app reads your fitness data and writes your tennis activity as a Workout to Health. The health data is correlated to your tennis activities.

Comment: I'm already using the "Other" workout type. It's just the distance which is not calculated.

Comment: Have you tried using TennisKeeper, or a similar app?